# Universal partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I made a partial for a site and my client loved it. It was basically just a sidebar that helps browse the database. Now he wants the sidebar all throughout the site on various pages. So, how can I call a partial from any controller without having to copy and paste the file into each directory.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try placing your partial in a folder call shared inside app/views and doing something like:

```
render :partial => 'shared/sidebar'
```

where you want to render the partial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

```
<%= render "partial_folder/partial_name" %>
```

Example:

```
<%= render "layouts/sidebar" %>
```

Comment: Ruby & Rails are about intuition :)